TypeError: maybeGlobalAsyncLocalStorage.snapshot is not a function in NextJS 15
I upgraded my Next project to 15.0.2 and now I'm getting this error:

TypeError: maybeGlobalAsyncLocalStorage.snapshot is not a function

  58 | ) => R {
  59 |   if (maybeGlobalAsyncLocalStorage) {
> 60 |     return maybeGlobalAsyncLocalStorage.snapshot()
     |                                         ^
  61 |   }
  62 |   return function (fn: any, ...args: any[]) {
  63 |     return fn(...args)

Github Issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/72074

It seems like there's an issue with the latest Next version. Downgrading to version 14.2.16 fixed the issue:
"next": "14.2.16",

